# @change on select passes argument 'event' which has no property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I'm working on a project with bootstrap-vue and vue-router.
I want to access event.target on @change, but I only get $event which only has selected value and does not have any properties.
What I thought is that $event is not a single value but an object which has some properties like target etc., but am I wrong?

Here is a snippet:

```
    <b-form-select plain :options="options" class="text-nowrap" @change="test($event)"></b-form-select>
```

```
export default {
 ...
  methods: {
    test: function(event) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(event)) // -> selected option value is shown
      console.log(JSON.stringify(event.target)) // -> shows "Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is expected because the component emits a `change` event with selected value: 
`this.$emit('change', this.localValue)`

https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/1b4985b8c9bf0e57000158ee0c0f237a1146811b/src/components/form-select/form-select.js#L102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using native event listener on the component:

```
<b-form-select plain :options="options" class="text-nowrap" 
   @change.native="test"></b-form-select>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and you saved me a lot of time... Thank you so much!